# Is there a way to add an index.php to a newly deployed domain in WHM?

Tags: web-hosting

Just a quick and simple question, is there a way to add an `index.php` to the `public_html`, to a newly deployed domain from the WHM?

Comment: What did cPanel support tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called the "skeleton directory".

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/SkeletonDirectory

The contents of `/root/cpanel3-skel/public_html` get placed in every new user's `public_html` folder.